# How to figure out the inception version of googlenet

Tags: neural-network, version

I have pretrained googlenet on Nvidia digits and I am unsure whether this is inceptionv1, inceptionv2 or inceptionv3. In DIGITs it just shows as GoogLenet. can any one tell me which version of inception this is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, Googlenet is considered as inception v1. The latest inception model, v3, could be used following the instructions of this link:
https://github.com/smichalowski/google_inception_v3_for_caffe